# Microsoft Edge does not render SVG style elements on ajax call to a gzipped SVG file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, svg

I am trying to get the content of a gzipped SVG file and append it to the HTML and work on the elements using `d3.js`. Everything is fine and all the content of the SVG file is being parsed and added to the DOM using jquery and all the browsers are rendering the style tag inside SVG content and applying all those styles to the SVG elements except Microsoft Edge.

By loading the SVG file directly from file URL (not by using ajax call) on the browser, everything is fine in Microsoft Edge. But, trying to get the content using ajax, it does not render styles and show black element as the images below:

[image: svg styles not rendered]

And this is how it shows up by loading the file from URL in Microsoft Edge:

[image]

This is the ajax code which I am using to call the file:

```
var settings = {
       "crossDomain": true,
       "url": file.svg,
       "method": "GET"
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {

    var floorPlanSVG = document.importNode(response.documentElement,true);

    $('#appendedFloorPlan').append(floorPlanSVG);

});
```

and this is how the content of the SVG is being added to the DOM:

[image]

The code is fine in all browsers, except Microsoft Edge (Screenshot from Google Chrome). Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: reminds me of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340293/3702797 I don't have edge at hand to help you out, but the ones who do will probably need some [MCVE]. At least the markup of a **minimal** (i.e just a `<rect>`) code which reproduces this behavior, at best, a working fiddle (maybe you can host incriminated file on some CORS ok service like dropbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just removed `document.importNode` and the problem is solved right now:

```
var floorPlanSVG = response.documentElement;
```